# Find largest files in a directory - Taking lot of time

Tags: find, ls

I'm trying to find the top 10 big files from a directory which has lot of sub directories and N number of files. My `find` command is running forever as its listing all the files and then gets in to sort mode. 
I need a faster execution. In my latest run the listing itself wasn't finished in 15 mins and I had to terminate the execution.

I have used the following `find` commands, none of them is executing fast and they hang:

```
find /opt/app -type f -print 2>/dev/null | xargs ls -lS 2>/dev/null |
    sort -k5,5rn | head -10

find /opt/app -xdev -ls | awk '{print $7, $11}' | " sort -rn "}' | head

find /opt/app -type f -exec ls -lS {} + 2>/dev/null | head -n 10 |
    awk '{ print $5, $9 }'
```

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: How many files in total? It could be that sorting the whole list is just _slow_. Since you only need the top ten, you could get a whole lot faster by storing and sorting only the ten largest. But I can't think of a tool that would do that automatically. It shouldn't be too hard to implement that in Perl or some other sufficiently high-level language (but I might just be promising too much).

Comment: With `zsh`: `ls -ldS /opt/app/**/*(DOL[1,10])`

Comment: For an interactive method, you can use `ncdu`. It can sort by size.

Comment: yes its the listing which kills the time and then followed by sorting.. :(

Comment: Since `du -s *` is very fast, you can implement a top-down algorithm that stops looking when a directory is smaller than the top-10 directories/files. If you have a few big files and many small files, this will be a lot faster then listing all files.

Comment: From your response to the answers so far I'm beginning to wonder what kind of filesystem you are using, and if you are perhaps experiencing some other problem. You write that you have 16 folders with 16 subfolders each, then thousands of files. This still doesn't strike me as _that_ much to process.

Comment: df -g /opt/app
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/optapp_lv    698.00    110.96   85%  3311317    12% /opt/app

Comment: since the files counts are high, using the find command is taking atleast 15 to 20 mins to process and sort the output.

Answer (score 6):

In any case, you will need to read the content of all directories in there and do a `lstat()`, which implies reading inode data to get the file size for all the files before you can determine which file is the largest.

And that disk (or network for networked file systems) I/O access, unless all the information is already cached in memory is the part that will take the most time.

There are quite a few unnecessary things that your approach does like converting user/group ids to user/group names, compute calendar representation of time stamps, decode bytes into characters that is going to keep your CPUs busy in addition to the disks, but disk I/O is likely to still be the bottleneck.

You can skip most of that unnecessary processing if you use for instance `zsh`'s globs and glob qualifiers:

```
ls -ldS /opt/apps/**/*(.DOL[1,10])
```

Note that `zsh` `O`rders the list of files by `L`ength (apparent size), but we still need `-S` for `ls` to order by `S`ize as otherwise `ls` would reorder them by name. With the GNU implementation of `ls`, you can use `-U` instead to skip the sorting. That implementation also supports a `-h` option for `h`uman-readable sizes (using KMGTPE... 1024-based suffixes) which has been copied by a many other implementations since.

Or with (recent) GNU tools:

```
(export LC_ALL=C # avoid decoding bytes into characters and
                 # complex sorting orders. Note that it may affect
                 # the ls -l output format though.
 find /opt/apps -type f -printf '%s/%p\0' |
   sort -srnz |
   head -z |
   cut -zd/ -f2- |
   xargs -r0 ls -ldS)
```

And see if that makes it any quicker.

Comment: Tip: Add an `h` to `-ldS` to make the size human readable :)  That is, make the last command `xargs -r0 ls -lhdS`

Comment: @LoremIpsum, thanks. I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 2):

`sort` doesn't provide output until all items have been sorted. It can't go back in the output and new items, so that's how it is. In my tests, GNU `sort` becomes active as soon is it gets enough output to start on its sorting algorithms, but holds off on output until everything has been sorted, so both `sort` and `find` were be active during the same time period (though `find` was active earlier, and `sort` remained active later, there was overlap).

The fastest way I can think of using `find` is to avoid other commands and text processing as much as possible. Thus, print the size and name using `find` itself instead of running `ls` multiple times. Using GNU find (and assuming filenames without newlines):

```
find /opt/app -xdev -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -k1,1n | head
```

<strike>Or you can run multiple `find`s in parallel:</strike>

```
(for d in /opt/app/*/; do find "$d" -xdev -type f -printf "%s %p\n" & done; wait) | sort -k1,1n | head
```

(this could turn out to be harmful because of output interleaving)

But you won't get any output until `sort` has done its work.

Comment: Those multiple finds will likely have their output improperly interleaved. It's unlikely to have any positive performance impact as the performance is going to be I/O bound here. Note that you don't need the `wait` as `sort` will wait for them anyway by virtue of waiting for eof on the pipe at the other end of which all the `find`'s are writing.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give to the top big files.

```
ls -l -R <folder path> | grep -v "^d" | awk '{print $5" "$9}' | sort -nrk1,1 | head -n10 | column -t
```

if you want the full path of the file as well, try the below:

```
find <folder path> -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -nr | head -10
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Siva.
The issue i face is /opt/app has 16 subdirectories then the 16 has other directories plus lots and lots of files. I have tried the commands you replied with, however its still executing for the last 10 mins and no response yet. 

This execution time is my biggest issue.

Comment: i tried the first command and i got the output. but it took 14mins

PRICE_HIST.ds.dsadm.dstageservsvc.0000.0000.0000.1ec00d2.5afb3193.0000.cd8f907c
7308574720 ITEM_LOC.ds.dsadm.dstageservsvc.0000.0002.0000.21300ee.5afb7964.0002.9d84a981
real    14m51.66s
user    1m51.14s
sys     0m39.59s

Comment: Try the second command, might give a better response  since we check only for files using `-type`

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that what you need, but:

```
ls -lR $(pwd) | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=9;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/ "$0 }' | egrep -v '^.|^$|^total\ ' | awk '{print $6,$1$NF}' | sort -nk1 | tail -n 10
```

Output:

```
13307 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/library/dellemc_configure_raid.py
14029 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/library/dellemc_configure_idrac_eventing.py
15199 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/library/dellemc_configure_idrac_users.py
20294 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/library/dellemc_configure_idrac_network.py
20851 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/samples/dellemc_get_firmware_inventory.md
35149 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/COPYING.md
49569 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/docs/OMAM_1.0.1_Readme.pdf
65486 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/samples/dellemc_get_system_inventory.md
89526 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/docs/OMAM_1.0.1_Installation_Guide.pdf
438419 /home/pierdolia/repo/Dell-EMC-Ansible-Modules-for-iDRAC/docs/OMAM_1.0.1_Users_Guide.pdf
```

only one cons: if directory contains too many files, that ls could not handle, so this won't work.

in my personal exp, I have noticed, that find works longer than these little commands, yes it's not "final" version, can be shrunk, but it's quite good.

P.S. If you remove first AWK it will display only filenames:

```
ls -lR $(pwd) | egrep -v '^.|^$|^total\ ' | sort -nk5 | tail -n 10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 13307 May 14 13:22 dellemc_configure_raid.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 14029 May 14 13:22 dellemc_configure_idrac_eventing.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 15199 May 14 13:22 dellemc_configure_idrac_users.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 20294 May 14 13:22 dellemc_configure_idrac_network.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 20851 May 14 13:22 dellemc_get_firmware_inventory.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 35149 May 14 13:22 COPYING.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia  49569 May 14 13:22 OMAM_1.0.1_Readme.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 65486 May 14 13:22 dellemc_get_system_inventory.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia  89526 May 14 13:22 OMAM_1.0.1_Installation_Guide.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pierdolia pierdolia 438419 May 14 13:22 OMAM_1.0.1_Users_Guide.pdf
```

or add additional awk:

```
ls -lR $(pwd) | egrep -v '^.|^$|^total\ ' | sort -nk5 | tail -n 10 | awk '{print $5,$NF}'
13307 dellemc_configure_raid.py
14029 dellemc_configure_idrac_eventing.py
15199 dellemc_configure_idrac_users.py
20294 dellemc_configure_idrac_network.py
20851 dellemc_get_firmware_inventory.md
35149 COPYING.md
49569 OMAM_1.0.1_Readme.pdf
65486 dellemc_get_system_inventory.md
89526 OMAM_1.0.1_Installation_Guide.pdf
438419 OMAM_1.0.1_Users_Guide.pdf
```

Comment: I have ran the first command, unfortunately took 16 mins... 


ls -lR /opt/app | grep -v '^.|^$|^total\ ' | sort -k5,5rn | head -10



real    16m37.29s
user    1m45.15s
sys     0m43.71s

Comment: how many files you have?

Comment: there are 3393854 files